# Java ExecutorService sequentially -Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executor

I want to implement the ExecutorService in my Spring-MVC application.

I need a global ExecutorService which take tasks put them in a queue and then executes them sequentially. So I want to pass the tasks from different locations in the application. Therefore I am using the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` so I have only 1 thread executing these tasks.

However, I am not sure how to integrate it in a Spring application:

```
public enum TaskQueue {

    INSTANCE;

    ExecutorService executorService;

    private TaskQueue() {
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void addTaskToQueue (Runnable task){
        executorService.submit(task);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

So I am thinking of creating a Singleton and then just passing the Task (Runnable object) to the method:

```
TaskQueue.INSTANCE.addTaskToQueue(new Runnable() {
 @Override
  public void run() {
      System.out.println("Executing Task1 inside : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
```

However, I have several questions:

I am not sure how to integrate it in a Spring MVC application where I have controllers, services and so on.

The application receives some notifications from a web-service. These notifications will be processed on different locations in the code. I want to 
execute them sequentially. So I need to identify all tasks I want to run asynchronously and then pass them to the method above (`addTaskToQueue) wrapped in a Runnabel object, so they can be executed asynchronously. Is this the correct approach?

So I always pass a Runnable objects to this method to execute it. This method executes it and shuts the executorservice down. So each time I pass a task to this service - it creates a new service and then closes it. But I dont want to have that - I want the executorservice to stay alive and execute the tasks that are comming and not shutdown after each task. How do I achieve this?

Or am I totally wrong in implementing it this way?

EDIT:

Using the TaskExecutor provided by Spring - I would implement it like this:

```
@Autowired
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
```

Then calling it from different location in my code:

```
taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO add long running task
        }
    });
```

Probably I need to make sure somewhere in the configuration that it needs to be executed sequentially - so it should create only 1 thread. Is it safe to call it from different locations? It wont always create a new service with a new queue?

Comment: Why do you shut down the `ExecutorService` immediately after adding a task to it?

Comment: @SeverityOne But when do I have to shut it down? I want to to pass tasks from multiple places in the spring application and I dont know where to put the shutdown.

Comment: When you no longer need it. I'd better write an answer for this.

Comment: My biggest problem is integrating the whole concept in a Spring MVC application. I have a web-service method which receives all the notifications and then other services are called to perform some tasks - Maybe I need it to put at the end of the web-service method?

Comment: @Norbert94 you set `maxNumber` of threads when configuring `taskExecutor` bean in XML or in Java config. By default Spring beans are singletons so only one instance of `taskExecutor` will be created per application context.

Comment: @Ivan Yeah sry - that was a stupid question. Of course Spring beans have only one instance. Do you generally agree with calling this method in different Services in my Spring application? Maybe I would run out of memory if there are to much tasks in the queue

Comment: @Norbert94, If you are afraid to get OOM in case of a lot of tasks added into the queue you could create `taskExecutor` with more then one thread. Also if you have different tasks (some set of tasks is a long-running and another set of tasks is fast to finish) you'd better have two different `taskExecutor` beans for those two types of tasks. But anyway it is OK to use this bean from several other beans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring already has a bean for this: `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. It implements `DisposableBean` interface and `shutdown()` method is called when Spring context is destroyed.

```
  <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${threadPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${threadPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer - I edited my question and provided a code sample for this approach - I would appreciate it if you could check it.

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton design pattern is not a very good fit for this. Since you're using Spring, it makes much more sense to make a component with `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` methods. [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/) and [here](https://www.boraji.com/spring-bean-life-cycle-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example) are articles that explain this.

In your case, I'd do something like the following:

```
@Component
public class TaskQueue {

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanup() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public void addTaskToQueue (Runnable task){
        executorService.submit(task);
    }
}
```

And then you can autowire this component.

Edit: @Ivan's answer is to be preferred.